# How do I set up a LaTeX document to look like this?

Tags: formatting

[image]

[Source](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Nelson.pdf)

I don't know enough about LaTeX to answer this one for myself! I'm almost expecting it just to be a standard LaTeX document.

Comment: Looks a bit like `\documentclass{amsart}`.

Answer (score 6):

I think that's a standard `amsart` document, e.g.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\author{A. N. Author}
\title{Stuff}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Stuff about stuff
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```